# Invalid username or password. Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I wanted to start trying to work with BitBucket.
I just created a repo and tried to push my first things, but when I "`$ git push origin master`", a window appears that asks for my username and password on bitbucket.
I introduce them correctly (the ones I log in bitbucket with) and this message appears

```
remote: Invalid username or password. 
If you log in via a third party service you must ensure 
you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://****@bitbucket.org/*********/******.git/'
```

I am using Windows.
I tried with MinGW and Tortoise, both gave me the same error.
What could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you are using [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases), your [credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) should be set to the [Microsoft Git-Credential-Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows), linked to the  [Credential Manager in Windows](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/101/2016/01/the-windows-vaults/).

So open that credential store to change your recordedcredentials there.

Second, double check your BitBucket account username and password. Make sure your account is the one displayed in `https://****@bitbucket.org/...`.
And make sure your password (for testing here) does not have any special characters (like `@`)

Answer (score 0):

> git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
>   git config --global credential.helper store (for window users)
>   it will reset your password

when you use source tree again it will promt you to access your key